# Patching a RavenDB document - multiple conditions used in LINQ query

Tags: linq, nosql, ravendb

For all documents satisfying a given criteria, I would like to patch update a field in those documents. For this, I wrote a query in LINQ Pad that gets me the subset of documents needed.

That is :

```
Session.Query<Movie>()    
.Where(x => x.Status == "Released" && x.IsDeleted == false && x.ReleaseDate.Date < new DateTime(2012, 4, 3))
.Dump();
```

Now I have the list of documents. But I need to modify a field. For this I wrote an index and patch command.. I need help completing this task.

Patch code (incomplete) :

```
  store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Movies/NewIndexName",
         new IndexQuery { Query = "IsDeleted:false" },
         new[]
        {
          new PatchRequest
              {
                  Type = PatchCommandType.Modify,
                  Name = "Status",
                  Value = "Testing"
               }
        }, allowStale: false);
```

Index is

```
  from doc in docs.Movies
  select new { ReleaseDate = doc.ReleaseDate.Date, IsDeleted = doc.IsDeleted, Status =

  doc.Status }
```

Specifically my question is.. is my approach correct.. and if it is, how do I add multiple criteria in the condition.. where it says Query = "IsDeleted:false" can I add more comparison checks to the query (like in the LINQ query above)?

EDIT: (USING DANIEL LANG'S SOLUTION)

This gives format exception.. Input string not in correct format.

```
store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Movies/NewIndexName",
             new IndexQuery
             {
                 Query =
         string.Format("Status:Released AND IsDeleted:false AND ReleaseDate:{* TO {0}}",
         DateTools.DateToString(new DateTime(2012, 4, 3),
                                DateTools.Resolution.MILLISECOND))
             },
             new[]
            {
              new PatchRequest
                  {
                      Type = PatchCommandType.Modify,
                      Name = "Status",
                      Value = "TestingReleased"
                   }
            }, allowStale: false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple conditions and combine them using standard boolean operations. You're actually building a lucene query here, so let's take a look at this website to learn more about how you can write them: http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Boolean%20operators

The thing about dates is, that raven stores them (as everything else) as a string and the format it uses is specifically chosen to enable range queries and that kind of stuff, so it might not be what you expect...

So in order to query for the date, you need to format it in a special way. There is a class DateTools inside Raven.Abstractions.Linq that has a DateToString method that helps.

You can construct the same query from above like this:

*(EDITED 4/27 to add an extra {} in the string)*

```
Query = 
    string.Format("IsDeleted:false AND ReleaseDate:{{* TO {0}}}",
    DateTools.DateToString(new DateTime(2012,4,3), 
                           DateTools.Resolution.MILISECONDS))
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.. how would you do a date comparison (less than, greater than etc..) in this case using the new datetools.datetostring? In particular I am trying to do this..  .Where(x => x.Status == "Released" && x.IsDeleted == false && x.ReleaseDate.Date < new DateTime(2012, 4, 3))

Comment: Is this correct?   Query =
         string.Format("Status:Released AND IsDeleted:false AND ReleaseDate:{* TO {0}}",
         DateTools.DateToString(new DateTime(2012, 4, 3),
                                DateTools.Resolution.MILLISECOND)).. is this same as ..  Where(x => x.Status == "Released" && x.IsDeleted == false && x.ReleaseDate.Date < new DateTime(2012, 4, 3))

Comment: Please see EDIT in OP. I am getting, FormatException was unhandled by user code.. error.. "input string was not in correct format"  ...

Comment: The query is actually the same as `x.ReleaseDate.Date < new DateTime(2012, 4, 3)`, because it is a range query 'from * to Date'. It's syntax is very similar in case you want to have > or >= syntax, although slightly different. In case you don't know the syntax for a particular query you can always genereate it from the linq query. As for the exception: I'll take at look a look at that (no VS here at this Mac right now...)

Comment: I'm sorry, I have absolutely no time these days, so I fear I won't be able to check that at least within the next 1-2 weeks.

Comment: Thats okay Daniell.. thanks for your help anyway.. Ayende spotted the need for an extra {} in the string.. that was the issue.. you can see the solution here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273253/format-exception-ravendb-linq-query

Answer (score 4):

You can write the query like this:

```
store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Movies/NewIndexName",
         new IndexQuery { Query = "IsDeleted:false AND Status:Release" },
         ....
```

**Note** You can always call `ToString()` on the LINQ query and see the Lucene query that is generated behind the scenes (or use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and watch the queries go over the wire)

```
Session.Query<Movie>()    
.Where(x => x.Status == "Released" && x.IsDeleted == false && x.ReleaseDate.Date < new DateTime(2012, 4, 3))
.ToString()
```

Comment: So we were posting these answers nearly the same second :)