# Format exception - RavenDB LINQ query

Tags: linq, nosql, ravendb

I am getting a input string format error in the following bit of code... While debugging code, this runs as a single line of code and so I am not able to dig deep into what might be causing the format exception.. can any one please point to me what I am doing wrong.. thank you.

Exception:

```
FormatException was unhandled by user code:
"Input string was not in correct format"
```

Code:

```
store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Movies/NewIndexName",
             new IndexQuery
             {
                 Query =
         string.Format("Status:Released AND IsDeleted:false AND ReleaseDate:{* TO {0}}",
         DateTools.DateToString(new DateTime(2012, 4, 3),
                                DateTools.Resolution.MILLISECOND))
             },
             new[]
            {
              new PatchRequest
                  {
                      Type = PatchCommandType.Modify,
                      Name = "Status",
                      Value = "TestingReleased"
                   }
            }, allowStale: false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is inside string.Format, You need the value to be:

```
    {{* TO {0}}}
```

In other words, you need to escape the { }

Comment: How would this work with utc format? it seems the DateTools.DateToString drops the trailing Z